# Responsive webpage - Resizing images as the outer div size changes?

Tags: html, css, resize, responsive-design

I'm designing a page which will have a few small images on it. I want them to be in two columns and grow/shrink as the window changes.

Take a look at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9WAa/):

You'll notice that as you resize the window, the pictures shift about so that when the window is small there is only one column and if the window is very wide there are many. Instead of this behaviour, I would like to resize the images so that there are always two columns.

I thought that it would be a simple case of setting the width to 45%... apparently not.

Heres the code from the Fiddle:

```
<div id="Thumbs">
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://goo.gl/LXa6K">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://goo.gl/LXa6K">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://goo.gl/LXa6K">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://goo.gl/LXa6K">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://goo.gl/LXa6K">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://goo.gl/LXa6K">
    </li>
</ul>
```

-

```
#Thumbs ul {
list-style: none;
}
#Thumbs ul li {
float:left;
margin: 10px 0 0 5%;
}
#Thumbs ul li img {
/*
How do you resize the images?
*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `height` and `width` in CSS to 100%.

```
#Thumbs ul li img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See the edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A9WAa/1/).

You can see the change in these screen shoots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think setting their size to 100% of the parent should work:

```
#Thumbs ul li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Untested!**

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoht/jHm8w/3/

Setting the image width too 100% is a good start

```
#thumb ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I updated your li styles to:

```
#Thumbs ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 5%;
  width: 44.6%;
}
```

Not sure why you set your li margin's to `margin: 10px 0 0 5%;` but I kept it that way. I updated the display and width. if you need the right column to be flush right, try adding

```
#thumbs ul li:nth-child(2n+2) {
  float: right;
}
```

Hope that helps.